# $z \cdot \cot(z)$ series

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, power-series

Let us consider an expansion $z \cot(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-4)^{n} \cdot B_{2n} \cdot \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$.

How to prove the RHS?

I see possible to come to the expansion $\pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z}-2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\zeta(2n) z^{2n}}$ but this does not seem to be helpful enough.

Regarding straightforward approach: it is possible to find an explicit series for $z \cdot \cot(z) = z \cdot  \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)} = A(z)$ and then try looking for the reccurence on the coefficients of $A(z)$ but it's related with to many computational difficulties.

It is more or less reasonable way to proceed it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that the Bernoulli numbers appear in the Taylor series of $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$? It's not hard to get the relation from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$f(z)= \frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!}\,z^n.\tag{1}$$
By replacing $z$ with $2iz$,
$$\frac{2iz}{e^{2iz}-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2i)^n B_n}{n!}\,z^n.\tag{2}$$
Now:
$$ z\cot z=iz\cdot\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}=iz\cdot\frac{e^{2iz}+1}{e^{2iz}-1}=iz+\frac{2iz}{e^{2iz}-1},\tag{3}$$
hence by $(2)$:
$$z\cot z = iz+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2i)^n B_n}{n!}\,z^n \tag{4}$$
and since the LHS is an even function, we may drop the $z^{\text{odd}}$ parts of the RHS:
$$z\cot z = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2i)^{2n} B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\,z^{2n}\tag{5}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Thank you.

As it turned up, all the knowlenge required was the $\frac{z}{e^{z}-1}$ expansion. )